# How can I calculate the initial velocities of a set of objects with a consistent force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass, velocity, projectile

I'm trying to figure out which object would have the largest time of flight when launched from a slingshot. To do this, I need the initial velocity. How can I calculate this if I know the mass and diameter of the object? The slingshot always has the same force. I've seen a number of formulas, but none of them take into account the mass and size, which would matter in this case (a 10kg, 10cm rock will not go as fast or as long as a 1kg, 1cm rock).

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you're modelling the slingshot as a spring, you can consider the potential energy stored within it when it's loaded is fully transferred to the kinetic energy of the projectile (neglecting the friction during the short acceleration etc.), and then it gets down to the ballistic of a freefalling object with air friction (see the [drag coefficient of a rough sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient) and the formula of [air friction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29)) which you can solve with Newton's 2nd law.

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted the energy conservation way (if you have spring constant and distance stretched)so here is the Newtons laws way:

If you know the mass of the object and the force on the object and the distance the has the force applied on it then you get the velocity as it leaves the slingshot (given newtons laws:

$\begin{align}F=ma \\\ F/m=a\end{align}$

Then we use our kinematics equations to solve for velocity knowing acceleration and distance by:

$v_{f}^2-v_{0}^2=2a\Delta x \longrightarrow v_{f}=\sqrt{2a\Delta x}=\sqrt{2(F/m)\Delta x}$

To take into account air resistance the force on the ball then becomes the force from the slingshot minus the force of air resistance which is

$F_{drag}=-bv^2$

Where $b$ is given by properties of the ball like shape, density, etc.
Taking into account air resistance while in the slingshot I believe is unnecessary. It should hardly affect the velocity of object as it leaves the slingshot. Where you should take it into account is after it leaves the slingshot. Your question asks how to find initial velocity and both answers tell you that.

Comment: It's not a problem, it's a real life scenario, so I believe air resistance does come I to play

Comment: If its real life scenario measure the distance it travels while in the slingshot. If air resistance is taken into account then there is an extra force called the drag. It essentially just changes F to F-bv^2. Check this out for more on drag http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)